# How can we trim on the left side of the image

Tags: css

When I'm trying to apply trim to the image, the image is only trimmed on the right side, not on the left side.

How can we trim on the left side of the image?

I'm using this CSS:

```css
.media {
  padding: 39% 0;
}
```

Comment: Look into clip() function of CSS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip

Answer (score 0):

You try the `object-fit` attribute.

```
.media {
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

This keeps the original aspect ratio of your image and covers the entire element. Parts that are outside of the element would be cropped.

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple ways to do that.

**1**. You can use `clip` attribute, that let's you to do clipping with an animation if you like.

```
.media {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0px,60px,200px,0px); // order of values like other css rules are cockwise (top, right, bottom, left)
}
```

**2**. Or you can use `object-fit` and then add a `object-position` attribute to set top and left position of your image (you can push your image to right and bottom using positive values and to top and left by negative values). And you can play with `width` and `height` to hide right and bottom parts of your image.

```
.media {
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: -20px 20px; // px or %
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

`object-fit` property can have following values:

- **fill**: This is default. The replaced content is sized to fill the element's content box. If necessary, the object will be stretched or squished to fit
- **contain**: The replaced content is scaled to maintain its aspect ratio while fitting within the element's content box
- **cover**: The replaced content is sized to maintain its aspect ratio while filling the element's entire content box. The object will be clipped to fit
- **none**: The replaced content is not resized
- **scale-down**: The content is sized as if none or contain were specified (would result in a smaller concrete object size)

**3.** If you're using css sprite technique it's better to set your image to background of `<img>` tag and then clip it using background css property.

```
.media {
    left: 63px;
    width: 44px;
    background: url(img_navsprites.gif) -47px 0;
}
```